# Intuition for the structure of the sets $E_\alpha$ in Jarnik's theorem, i.e. reals $x$ s.t. $|x-(p/q)|\leq q^{-(2+\alpha)}$ for infinitely many $p/q$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, reference-request, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I am looking to better understand the structure of the set $E_\alpha$ associated to the Jarnik's theorem (according to Wolff T.H, *Lectures on Harmonic Analysis*, Ch. 9, pp̣. 67): Let $\alpha > 0$ be fixed and define

$$E_\alpha=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid \text{exists infinitely many unique rationals $\frac{p}{q}$ such that }\left|x - \frac{p}{q}\right|\leq q^{-(2 + \alpha)}\right\}$$

Then what seems to be the *Jarnik's Theorem* is that the set $E_\alpha$ has a Hausdorff dimension of $\frac{2}{2 + \alpha}$. I am not that interested in the theorem itself, but rather on the structure of the set $E_\alpha$. Specifically, what would be some examples of sets $E_\alpha$? Do we know any qualitative properties of the elements of $E_\alpha$? Clearly $E_\alpha\neq \varnothing, \forall \alpha > 0$ for $\forall \alpha > 0:0\in E_\alpha$. Do we know what kinds of elements are included to $E_\alpha$ from a small (or large) neighbourhood of the origin?

If you happen to know a good source discussing these things, feel free to post it!

Comment: The continued fraction for $x$ gives a sequence of rationals such that  $|x-p/q|<1/q^2.$ When $x$ is rational, there are only finitely many $p/q.$ If irrational, there are infinitely many. So we can think of $\alpha$ as a measure of how far away $x$ is from a rational number.

Comment: Basically, larger $\alpha$ means the big coefficients of the continued fraction have to be larger.

Comment: If $c_n$ are the coefficients of the continued fraction, and $P_n/Q_n$ are  the convergents, then you will need infinitely many $n $ such that $c_{n+1}>Q_n^{\alpha},$ or something approximately like that. Since $Q_n$ grows at least exponentially, so the large coefficients have to be very large.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Interesting! Do you happen to know a reference which discusses the your first two comments or a proof for them? Namely, if $x=\frac{a}{b}$ then why only finitely many rationals $\frac{p}{q}$ approximate $x$ in the aforementioned way? And If $x$ is irrational, then why does its rational expansion yield such a sequence?

Comment: The rational case is easy. If $x=\frac ab\neq \frac pq,$ then $|x-p/q|=\frac{|qa-bp|}{aq}\geq \frac1{bq}.$ So you'd need $bq>q^2,$ which means there can only be finitely many values $q.$ The irrational  case follows from basic facts about continued fractions. $$\left|x-\frac{P_n}{Q_n}\right|<\frac1{Q_{n}Q_{n+1}}<\frac1{Q_{n}^2}.$$ That should be covered in all places where continued fractions are covered, though I don't have a specific reference off the top of my head.